# How can I force a timestamp update in Laravel 5.1 when performing a raw INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, timestamp

I use DB::statement($query, $params) to perform batch inserts into my database with the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax. However, when I do, neither the 'updated_at' or 'created_at' fields are updated. I am wondering if there is a way to force the correct field to be updated in the raw query?

Context: I am using Laravel 5.1 and have created the relevant tables using the $table->timestamps() feature. In addition to doing raw insert/updates, I also query these tables using Eloquent so I cannot implement a solution that would disable Eloquent's auto-updates.

Concerns: I am not clear at the moment how times are generated when Eloquent automatically updates a timestamp field - I assume it triggers an auto-update in the database with reference to the database's reference clock? I would like to mimic however Eloquent is going about it so that I don't end up with times using two different clocks as sources.

I am very new to using raw MySQL queries so appreciate in advance any advice/insight folks are able to offer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to figure out a way to auto-trigger timestamp inserts/updates when using raw database queries so I ended up hard coding them into my queries.

I added the `created_at` column to my raw `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` column lists as needed. Then, I implemented a method to auto-generate the update column-value pairs that swaps in `updated_at` in place of `created_at` as the column for the given time value.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

// use insertGetId method

    $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([]);

// and now update your table using where method

    DB::table('users')->update([
                             'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                             'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                       ])->where('id',$id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think it will achieve quite what I am after. I believe the insertGetId() method - like the insert() method - doesn't allow for the 'on duplicate key update' part of the query - that's why I had to go with a raw query. Also, I would like to update either the created_at or updated_at field, depending on whether the raw query ends up doing an insert or an update, rather than both fields. I was hoping there might be raw MySQL query syntax that could trigger the appropriate timestamp column to update.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not clear at the moment how times are generated when Eloquent
>   automatically updates a timestamp field - I assume it triggers an
>   auto-update in the database with reference to the database's reference
>   clock?

No. Laravel is using the `Carbon` class which internaly is using PHPs `DateTime` class. You can see that in the [source code of the `save()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1466). Track: `save() -> performInsert() -> updateTimestamps() -> freshTimestamp() -> new Carbon`

> I would like to mimic however Eloquent is going about it so that I
>   don't end up with times using two different clocks as sources.

You can create the same timestamp as Eloquent would with:

```php
$currentTimestamp = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Or if you have any `Model` instance:

```php
$currentTimestamp = $model->freshTimestampString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and link) as to what's going on under the hood with save(). I ended up using Carbon to create the timestamp and added it to my raw query.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with Eloquent
I suppose you have already your ID

```
<?php
// $id your id
$object = Model::find($id);

// If is null you make insert row on your DB
if(null===$object) Model::create($inputs);

// If not null you make update row on your DB
else $object->fill($inputs)->save();
```

If you do like this eloquent manages created_at and updated_at

Comment: 'Fraid I can't use Eloquent on this one as I am trying to create or update multiple models all in one call to the database, rather than cycling through each one individually. So far as I have been able to determine, there is no Eloquent method that accesses the functionality of the MySQL query (INSERT... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) that allows for the creation - or, if the model already exists, updating - of a large number of models with a single DB call. Thanks for taking a stab at the question though!